# MSXML and newline normalization(?) of Document.xml property

Tags: newline, msxml

I created following simple xml (C escape sequence used) "`<A>\n</A>`"
When `MSXML` (v4 and v6) serialize DOM document using IXMLDOMDocument2.xml it changes newline to dos format and returns: "`<A>\r\n</A>`" instead.

When I use DOM to retrieve only string node inside `<A>` element I get correct single character `("\n")` string.

Of course I have `preserveWhiteSpace` set to `VARIANT_TRUE`

`XML.Net` and Xerces parsers works fine and do not modify the stored string while serializing the xml document.

Is that a bug in msxml? any idea?

thx Jiri

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft changed the way that newline serialization is handled in MSXML 4 onwards to comply with the w3wc standards  (See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/261293)

I have no idea why the same wasn't done for for the xml implementation in .Net, but the same **is** done for web services in .Net 2.0.

When I had this problem last I came to the conclusion that you either need to account for the fact that newline characters may be serialised unpredictably (for example by replacing `\r\n` with `\n`), or you need to base-64 encode your text (or equivalent)